# Segmentation fault in structure in C

Tags: c, struct

Hello I'm trying to make simple program that will check if student assessment is greater than 5.50. When I try to enter the var "number in class" I get SEGFAULThere is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct student{
    char name[100];
    int number_in_class;
    double assessment;
}student;

int main(void){
    student corrective[25];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 25; i++){
        printf("Ime na uchenika:\n");
        scanf("%s", corrective[i].name);
        printf("Nomer v klas:\n");
        scanf("%i", corrective[i].number_in_class);
        printf("ocenka:\n");
        scanf("%f", corrective[i].assessment);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 25; i++){
        if(corrective[i].assessment >= 5.50){
            printf("Ime: %s\nNomer v klas: %i\nOcenka: %i\n",corrective[i].name, corrective[i].number_in_class ,corrective[i].assessment);

        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the address of the objects to `scanf()`, not their values

```
    for(i = 0; i < 25; i++){
        printf("Ime na uchenika:\n");
        scanf("%s", corrective[i].name); // array converted to pointer to 1st element (an address)
        printf("Nomer v klas:\n");
        scanf("%i", &corrective[i].number_in_class); // use & to pass the address
        printf("ocenka:\n");
        scanf("%lf", &popravitelni[i].assessment); // same as before
    }
```

As other posters have noted, you need `"%lf"` for addresses of objects of type `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `%lf` to read a `double` object and not `%i` or`%f`. For `printf`, use `%f` to print a `double`. Also you need to pass pointers for `scanf` arguments. Enable all your compiler warnings and fix them.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters to `scanf()` are incorrect. You have to pass them as pointers.

`scanf("%s", corrective[i].name);` is correct, because `corrective[i].name` is an array therefore a pointer by definition, but you cannot do the same with the other primitive data types. Head then with `&` to get its pointer.

```
...
scanf("%i", &corrective[i].number_in_class);
...
scanf("%f", &corrective[i].assessment);
```

In addition you should check the types you are reading as mentioned in [ouah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22439897/156811).

Comment: in most uses, an array is converted to a pointer to its first element. Exceptions are when arrays are used as operands to `sizeof` operator or the "address-of" operator or when they are used as initializers for string literals.

Comment: I am aware of that. But those details have no importance in the merit of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `%i` in this statement:

```
scanf("%i", corrective[i].number_in_class);
```

while the number_in_class is a double. Use `%lf`, thats used for `double`. Also correct `%f` to `%lf` in this statement too:

```
scanf("%f", popravitelni[i].assessment);
```

Also use `&`-the address-of operator to pass the address instead of value in the `scanf()` function.

Corrected Code:

```
scanf("%lf", &corrective[i].number_in_class);
.
.
scanf("%lf", &popravitelni[i].assessment);
```